# Scala: value :: is not a member of Int

Tags: scala

I recently started using scala and I can't make anything of the error messages. For the following code I get the stated message(using eclipse):

```
def helper: Int => List[Int] = x =>  x match  {
    case 2 => 2::1
    ...
}
```

I can fix it by using List(2,1), but souldn't that be the same thing as 2::1?
I have similar problems where the List(...) approach would be harder to use, so I really want to know where my thinking mistake is.

Comment: 2 :: 1 :: Nil
try this

Comment: Or, better: `List(2,1)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Infix operators are interpreted as method calls in Scala. If the infix operators ends with a colon, it's a method call on the right operand with the left operand as its argument. Otherwise it's a method call on the left operand with the right operand as its argument.

In other words, if you do `x + y`, it's the same as `x.+(y)`, i.e. you're calling the method `+` on the object `x`, with `y` as the argument. And if you do `x :: y` it's the same as `y.::(x)`, calling the method `::` on the object `y`.

So in your example you're calling the method `::` on the object `1`, which is an `Int`. However the class `Int` does not have a `::` method, so this does not work and you get an error message telling you that the `::` method does not exist for the `Int` class.

To make `::` work, the right operand needs to be a list (or something else that has a `::` method), so `2 :: 1 :: Nil` would work. However in this case using `List()` seems like the cleaner alternative.

Comment: Thanks, now I got it.
So in the case of + the right side is the argument
and for :: its the left?

Answer (score 3):

The expression `2::1` is interpreted in Scala as:

```
{ val x = 2; 1.::(x) }
```

because operators ending in a colon `:` are right-associative and if `op` is right-associative, then `e1 op e2` is interpreted as `{ val x = e1; e2.op(x) }` (see [Scala Language Reference, Section 6.12.3, p. 84, which is p. 92 of the PDF](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf#page=92)).

For the purposes here, basically the following simplified version is called

```
1.::(2)
```

However, `1` is of type `Int` and `Int` does not have a method with name `::` (and there is also no implicit conversion to another type that has such a method), hence the error.

As ayvango has pointed out above, you could use

```
2::1::Nil
```

which is interpreted as

```
Nil.::(2).::(1)
```

Now this works perfectly well, because `Nil` is of type `List[Nothing]` and does have a method `::`, see [scala.collection.immutable.List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) Furthermore, `::` returns something of type `List[Int]`, so the subsequent call `.::(1)` is also fine.

Another way is

```
2::List(1)
```

which becomes `List(1).::(2)` and works for the same reason as above.

Your confusion might be due to the fact that you consider `List(2,1)` to be the same as `2::1`, however, it is actually `2::1::Nil`. Think of lists as being built inductively as follows:

- `Nil` is a list
- if `head` is an element and `tail` is a list, then `head::tail` is a list

as witnessed by the implementation of lists (simplified version, omitting traits)

```
sealed abstract class List[+A]
final case class ::[B](head: B, tl: List[B]) extends List[B]
object Nil extends List[Nothing]
```

Thus, lists always "end with" `Nil` in the `::` form of presentation.

On a sidenote, you could also try to automatically wrap `Int` into `List[Int]` by using something like

```
implicit def wrap(x : Int) : List[Int] = List(x)
```

or use similar functionalities provided by libraries such as [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) but this might not always be desirable and probably is a bit beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2):

:: is a method defined on List. You are trying to use this operator with Int type.
Take a look at: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List

As @ayvango pointed out, you could do:

```
def helper: Int => List[Int] = x =>  x match  {
  case 2 => 2 :: 1 :: Nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `::` operator, on `Int` or other types like `string`, just add **Nil** to the end of the list, otherwise you get this error:

> value :: is not a member of Int

this **won't** be compiled:

```
println(0::1::2::3::4::5)
```

but this will get compiled:

```
 println(0::1::2::3::4::5::Nil)
```

[image: value :: is not a member of Int]